# Открытие fragment

Tags: java, android

Данный код позволяет выдвигать шторку с меню, пока никакой пункт меню не выбран, главное активити пустует. Как при открытии приложения сразу открывать фрагмент.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {


DialogF dialogF;

String savedLogin,savedPass;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);






    }
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

     dialogF = new DialogF();




}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
   int id = item.getItemId();
    //FragmentTransaction ftranse = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ftranse = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        ftranse.replace(R.id.conteiner,dialogF);

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }ftranse.commit();

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

вот так я заменюя фрагменты и не знаю как правильней решить данную задачу

```
ftranse.replace(R.id.conteiner,dialogF);
```

думал в конце условий дописать

```
...
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }else{
реплейс фрагмент 
}
```

но не сработало

Answer (score 1, accepted):

добавьте код вставки фрагмента в самый низ метода onCreate() вашей активити

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ...................

    //чтобы предовратить переход при пересоздании активити из-за поворота
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {            
        getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.conteiner,dialogF)
            .commit();
    }
}
```